# Remove floorboard glue from mitre saw

Tags: wood, adhesive, removal

I just bought a cheap Bosch mitre saw from eBay in pretty good working condition.

Only thing is that its covered in what I have been told is floorboard adhesive. Kind of light brown glue.

Its over all the metal and plastic.

Is there a solvent that won't harm the metal or plastic and tools I can use to remove it?

http://m.ebay.com.au/itm/Bosch-GCM-10S-Sliding-Mitre-Saw-Item-supplied-/222234264739?txnId=0

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd attempt to remove adhesive from the plastic, especially with a solvent.  For the metal, I've had good luck with acetone, but keep in mind that it can also remove paint.

Comment: As others have implied, plastic+glue=problem... I'd just leave it. But to get the glue off the metal saw table, try a razor blade/olfa blade/chisel. You want that surface flat.

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to remove adhesive from plastics as they bind. You may have luck with the blade.

For the blade, Heat and friction is probably your best bet.

Heat up the cutting blade with a blow torch, then use a chisel or scraper to remove the softened adhesive.

If that doesn't work you can use alcohol and scrape it off, but that could take a while.

Just remember to be safe. Heated metal can leave nasty burns, and slipping whilst scraping can cause damage to your skin.

Comment: Ah, I misread. I don't think it's possible to remove most adhesives from plastic as they bind. I'll leave my answer up for now.

Answer (score 1):

> Most adhesives harden over time, eventually petrifying. This makes
>   removal extremely difficult, and you will need to use a flooring
>   adhesive remover to soften the adhesive for removal.

http://homeguides.sfgate.com/use-flooring-adhesive-remover-46299.html

Obviously you'll want to do a test on some inconspicuous portion of the tool to determine whether the solvent damages the plastic housing, rubber wiring and grommets, decals, etc. Use water sparingly to avoid damaging the motor.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the metal parts and replace the plastic ones which the cleaning solvent damaged or couldn't clean. Usually not too expensive but shop around for the parts; prices from manufacturers can be a steal or a rip-off and the same parts can be had for major brands through many sources online.

Phil